# How to define KML Name element when using QgsVectorFileWriter?

Tags: qgis, kml

I am trying to use QgsVectorFileWriter to write a kml file from an active layer in QGIS, but cannot figure out how to define the KML Name element (called NameField in the QGIS save-as GUI) to correspond with a field in my shapefile, which is called "TYPE".

This code does not cause an error, but I cannot figure out how to define StringList to specify that the NameField column name is "Type":

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, kmlPointFile, "UTF-8", None, "KML", onlySelected = 0, datasourceOptions = StringList)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have switched to using gdal through python - my solution is:

```
cmd = 'ogr2ogr -f GPX -dsco NameField=TYPE {0} {1}'.format(outFile, inFile)
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, so can you juste give me the full solution for your code is that possible please, because with juste this line i dont know how can I use it in `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat`. Thank you