# Defining KML Name element when using QgsVectorFileWriter

Tags: pyqgis, kml

I am trying to use QgsVectorFileWriter to write a kml file from a Shape file.
I would like to define the KML Name (called NameField in the QGIS save-as GUI) to correspond with a field in my shapefile, which is called "NAME".

The solution given in [How to define KML Name element when using QgsVectorFileWriter?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118184) doesn't work for me.

Below is my code

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsVectorLayer

data_source = r"C:\Users\....\PT.shp"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(data_source, "layer_name", "ogr")
output_layer = r"C:\Users\....\PT_test"
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output_layer, "utf-8",layer.crs(),"KML",datasourceOptions = "NAME")

print ("Layer to KML Conversion Complete")
print (output_layer + " is now a .kml")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be a list:

```
    name = "NAME"
    datasource_options = []
    datasource_options += ["DescriptionField=" + name]
    datasource_options += ["NameField=" + name]

    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output_layer, "utf-8",layer.crs(),"KML",datasourceOptions = datasource_options)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @john, can you tell me please how can I convert multiple active layers in qgis to one file KML if is that possible.?